# Google N-Gram Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I wish to use Google 2-grams for my project; but the data size renders searching expensive both in terms of speed and storage.
Is there a Web-API available for this purpose (in any language) ? The website http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph renders an image, can I get data values?

Comment: With almost a decade having passed since this was asked, and this being a top result for all related Google ngram questions, I think it's worth noting download locations. Example is https://storage.googleapis.com/books/ngrams/books/datasetsv3.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, I got a round about way of doing that, using [Google BigQuery](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/)
In that, trigrams are available in public domain. Using [Command line access](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/hello_bigquery) did the job for me.

Comment: How did you reach the ngram data? I couldn't see it in Sample Datasets !

Comment: open https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/?pli=1, (and accept the terms and conditions and all that if not yet done and open back the link), then in the left side panel, select "trigrams" under "publicdata:samples"

Comment: Another alternative is a web service called [PhraseFinder](http://phrasefinder.io)

Comment: **In 2023** there is also [NGRAMS](https://ngrams.dev) as an alternative.

Answer (score 8):

I found a great alternative: **Microsoft Web N-Gram**

It can be queried in different ways, including a straighforward GET call through the [REST interface](http://web-ngram.research.microsoft.com/info/rest.html). 
For instance, calling the URL:

```
http://weblm.research.microsoft.com/weblm/rest.svc/bing-body/apr10/1/jp?u={YOUR_TOKEN}&p=red+panda
```

returns

```
-9.005
```

which is the log likelihood of the phrase `red panda`.

Furthermore, it is handier than Google N-Grams, as for a given phrase it does not simply output its absolute frequency, but it can output its joint probability, conditional probability and even the most likely words that follow.

*Disclaimer: I am not a Microsoft employee, I simply think that I just found an awesome service.*

Comment: I've just requested an API key from MS. The only mechanism offered to register is  by sending an email. Seems to me that there is no automated registration for the Microsoft service.

Comment: That's true. I also found that a weird choice.

Comment: Hmmm. web-ngram.research.microsoft.com took too long to respond.