# Scraping https website using getURL

Tags: r

I had a nice little package to scrape [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams) data but I have discovered they have switched to SSL and my package has broken. If I switch from `readLines` to `getURL` gets some of the way there, but some of the included script in the page is missing. Do I need to get fancy with user agents or something?

Here is what I have tried so far (pretty basic):

```
library(RCurl)
myurl <- "https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hacker&year_start=1950&year_end=2000"
getURL(myurl)
```

Comparing the results to viewing the source after entering the url in a browser shows that the crucial content is missing from the results returned to R. In the browser, the source includes content looking like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var data = [{"ngram": "hacker", "type": "NGRAM", "timeseries": [9.4930387994907051e-09,
  1.1685493106483591e-08, 1.0784501440023556e-08, 1.0108472218003532e-08,
```

etc.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The data you cite was not in the code my browser displayed but this was in there: <center id=\"datasets-announcement\">\n  Run your own experiment!  Raw data is available for download\n  <a href=\"/ngrams/datasets\">here</a>

Comment: I have played around with the raw data pointed to there, but there you have gigabtytes of data: the complete ngram datasets. Scraping the website allows you to simply query those datasets for the frequencies of a few words/phrases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, not a direct solution, but it doesn't seem to be an user-agent problem. When you open your URL in a browser, you can see that there is a redirection that adds a parameter at the end of the address : `direct_url=t1%3B%2Chacker%3B%2Cc0`.

If you use `getURL()` to download this new URL, complete with the new parameter, then the javascript you are mentioning is present in the result.

Another solution could be to try to access data via Google BigQuery, as mentioned in this SO question :

[Google N-Gram Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260833/google-n-gram-web-api)

Comment: I hadn't spotted that extra bit tacked on the end there! Presumably it is designed to thwart the likes of me ;) Anyway, I can now retrieve the data. Now to rework my parsing routine as it's in a different format than it used to be...

Comment: Thanks again for your help...[ngramr package now fixed on CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ngramr/index.html)!