# Structuring BigQuery with large array of data as input

Tags: google-bigquery

I am interested in obtaining the most frequently word associations with a particular word via BigQuery's ability find trigrams data. For example, when using Google's [Ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=great%20*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cgreat%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bgreat%20deal%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgreat%20and%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgreat%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgreat%20number%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgreat%20many%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgreat%20part%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgreat%20importance%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgreat%20measure%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgreat%20as%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgreat%20extent%3B%2Cc0), I could input `great *`, which will give me the most frequently associated word that follows "great", such as "great deal", then "great and" and "great many". My goal is to do it for a large list of words so that I could query with `word1 *` all the way to `word10000 *`

Following the discussion on this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260833/google-n-gram-web-api), I was led to the BigQuery's publicly available trigram data. What I can't seem to figure out at this point is how to use this service with input of an array of words, either as a file input or a way to paste them in. Any assistance is much appreciated - thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you would find 10 most frequent words to follow "great":

```
SELECT second, SUM(cell.page_count) total 
FROM [publicdata:samples.trigrams] 
WHERE first = "great"
group by 1
order by 2 desc
limit 10
```

This results in

```
second     total     
------------------
deal       3048832   
and        1689911   
,          1576341   
a          1019511   
number     984993    
many       875974    
importance 805215    
part       739409    
.          700694    
as         628978
```

If you wanted to limit to specific years - say between 1820 and 1840, then you can also restrict on cell.value (which is year of publication)

```
SELECT second, SUM(cell.page_count) total FROM [publicdata:samples.trigrams] 
WHERE first = "great" and cell.value between '1820' and '1840'
group by 1
order by 2 desc
limit 10
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks Mosha and it did the trick. As a follow up question, would it be possible to load multiple words to `first` so that I could generate a list for (ideally) 100 first words? I tried syntax such as "great, good, baseball, ..." or "great", "good", "baseball", ... but none of them so far were functional. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Try using `IN`. That is, `WHERE first IN ("great", "good", "baseball")`. You might also want to group by `first` as well if you do that, so you can see what the first word was as well as the second.

Comment: Thanks for the help @JordanTigani. Using `IN` worked to produce the combined result of the three words. I was wondering how I could perform the query so it would look up the individual words and provide a sum list - in other words, the number of columns in the result would be 2x the number of words I used to look up. Using "great", "good" and "baseball" would then have a 6 column table.

Comment: Getting 2x the number of columns is trickier, but you can use both the first and second words as grouping keys to approximate what you're asking:

SELECT first, second, SUM(cell.page_count) total 
FROM [publicdata:samples.trigrams] 
WHERE first = "great"
group by 1, 2
order by 1, 2 desc
limit 10

If that isn't sufficient, ask again and I'll give you the more complex solution.

Comment: Thanks for the help @DanDelorey! I tried the suggested code as well as modifying it, but couldn't get the desired solution. I explained things in greater detail in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33927175/structuring-bigquery-on-trigrams-with-multiple-inputs - appreciate the help!